# Getting database values from post* events

Tags: c#, nhibernate

my goal is to log all changes (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) made to the database. At the moment I use the "state" properties of the event args from the event listener API of NHibernate.

Unfortunately this doesn't work well if the changed property itself is another entity or if a user type is used. In these cases I would like to log the entity's Id/the value of the db columns etc.

But I did not found any data in the event args (IEntityPersister, ISession, etc.) that contain the original values of the db columns. Is this actually possible?

Here's a sample where an INSERT operation in handled. result.DatabaseValues contains the changed data.

```
private DatabaseOperation CreateInsertOperation(PostInsertEvent @event, LoggedClassConfiguration entityLoggingConfiguration)
  {
     string tableName = @event.Persister.QuerySpaces.First();
     DatabaseOperation result = ...

     object[] newState = @event.State;
     for (int i = 0; i < newState.Length; i++)
     {
        object newValue = newState[i];

        PropertyColumnMapping map = entityLoggingConfiguration.GetMapping(@event.Persister.PropertyNames.ElementAt(i));
        if (map == null)
        {
           continue;
        }

        result.DatabaseValues.Add(new DatabaseValue
        {
           NewValue = newValue,
           FieldName = map.DatabaseColumnName
        });
     }

     return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a logger this way:

```
var persister = anEvent.Persister;
for (int i = 0; i < persister.PropertyNames.Length; i++)
{
    var propertyType = persister.PropertyTypes[i];
    if (!propertyType.IsCollectionType)
    {
        var insertEvent = anEvent as PostInsertEvent;
        if (insertEvent != null)
        {
            var logEntry = (AuditLog) baseLog.Clone();
            logEntry.PropertyName = persister.PropertyNames[i];
            logEntry.PropertyNewValue = this.GetStateValue( insertEvent.State[i] );
            logger.DebugFormat( "Feld hinzugefuegt: '{0}' => '{1}'", logEntry.PropertyName, logEntry.PropertyNewValue );
            Session.Save( logEntry );
        }
    }
}
```

With this Way you get every propter which is inserted into the database. The only problem you have is with collection types and the references.

If I implemented an AuditLogging today, I would persist all Information into XML into a CLOB Database field.

Comment: Thanks for your solution to this problem. But you're not getting the actual database values, are you? What if user types are used? And how does this handle foreign key line an address id of a person?

Comment: With our convention we store a special ToStringValue()-Value required by all objects to be loged (via an Interface called IAuditable). this value is persisted when having a foreign key reference. this should deliver you the current values which are also saved within the database, i think. never noticed another behaviour. I haven't really used usertype yet.